# Aligning Point Cloud Positions with Normals for Improved Accuracy

Tags: python, math, 3d, geometry, open3d

[image]
I have a point cloud with noise (Figure A), and I also have accurate normalized normals for these points (Figure C).

Is there a way to align the positions of the points based on the normals in order to obtain a more accurate point cloud (Figure D)?

Here's some pseudocode that might be useful:

```py
import open3d as o3d

point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
point_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)  # Figure A
point_cloud.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(normals)  # Figure C
estimated_point_cloud = point_cloud.estimate_normals()  # Figure B
```

In essence, if I have a point cloud resembling a sphere with normals oriented as if they were from a cube, I would like to obtain a shape more resembling a cube.

I'm using Python and Open3D, but I'm open to solutions using other libraries, languages, and tools. Any help or suggestions on what to study would be greatly appreciated.

I have limited experience in this field, and a cursory exploration of library capabilities has yielded no results. I have found several solutions that allow aligning one point cloud with respect to another or improving geometry, but they don't quite suit my needs.

If this could be helpful:
I only have a noisy point cloud and fairly accurate normals.
The point cloud and normals were obtained using two different neural networks.

Comment: I don't understand. Seems you want to move each point in the direction and intensity given by the normal at that point and you hope the curved polygon becomes a perfect rectangle. If "true" points were in a rectangle then their normals would be all aligned with that rectangle. You may choose who is more important, the rectangle or the normals.

Comment: A rectangle (or better, each of its four segments) can be fit by Linear Regression, without using the normals.